# Laplace transform of $x^2$

Tags: laplace-transform

I can't seem to be able to understand why $$\mathcal{L}(x^n)(s) = \frac{n}{s} \mathcal{L}(x^{n-1})(s)$$ This one line has got me stuck! I know that $$\mathcal{L}(f(x)g(x)) \neq F(s)G(s)$$ so how could this line be valid.Please help.

Comment: Try an [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By parts:

$$u=x^n\,\,\Longrightarrow u'=nx^{n-1}\\v'=e^{-sx}\,\,\Longrightarrow v=-\frac{e^{-sx}}{s}$$

$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-sx}x^n\,dx=\left.-\frac{x^ne^{-sx}}{s}\right|_0^\infty+\frac{n}{s}\int\limits_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-sx}\,dx$$

Now just check the first term in the RHS above is zero...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{L}(x)(s) \neq  \frac{n}{s}$ then no contradiction.

Comment: Can you please expand a little more?

Comment: @levap if we get $F(z) = x , G(z) = x^{n-1}$ then both formula are true together and no thing to contradiction.